# Image load on iOS simulator but not on iPad

Tags: objective-c, image, ipad

The title pretty much describe my problem. I have a UIButton on which I applied a .png background. The .png load fine on the iOS simulator but not on the actual iPad. Any hints as to why it does that ?

EDIT:

When the view with the button in question loads I get this error message in the console

```
Could not load the "fosse.png" image referenced from a nib in the bundle with identifier "ca.polymtl.PolyPuttZE"
```

Comment: Do you set the image programmatically or in the Interface Builder?

Comment: The device is case sensitive, the simulator is not. Make sure the casing of the name is correct.

Comment: The file name is all lower-case as is the loaded image in interface builder

Answer (score 2):

Try doing this.

In Xcode press:

1. Command+Shift+K and press Yes.
2. Command+Shift+Alt+K and press Yes.
3. The try building, running.

Also, check if the image has correct targets (you can check by clicking on the image in Xcode and then in Inspector you'll find build targets).

Comment: Thanks for the shortcut ( 2. ) and the Target Membership panel in the Inspector.

Answer (score 1):

I've solved the problem. Turns out that the image wasn't encoded as a png even if it had the proper extension. So I juste opened it with gimp and exported it as a PNG.

Answer (score 0):

Click on your project. Then go to the `Build Phases` tab and ensure that the file is in the `Copy Bundle Resources` list.

If not then add it...